# Contraction of a tensor and a psudo-tensor?

Tags: tensors

Consider the tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ (e.g. the Faraday tensor) and the psudo-tensor $\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$. If we contract these:
$$T^{\alpha \beta}=F_{\mu \nu}\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$$
what type of quantity is $T^{\alpha \beta}$? What if we contract again:
$$A=F_{\mu \nu}F_{\alpha \beta}\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$$
is this a 'Lorenz-invariant' quantity or not?

Comment: There are two different notions ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor)) attached to the name "pseudo-tensor". What definition are you using?

Comment: @Arthur that as defined in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284067/70392 to one of my previous equations i.e.  the non GR version on the linked wiki page.

Comment: Then have you tried to apply your definition to $T$ and $A$?